# Sending value of radiobutton using ajax to node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, express

I am trying to send the value of a radiobutton using Ajax to my express/node app but I am having a problem (I am new to ajax). There are several other posts regarding this topic but I can't seem to get mine to work. I am creating a multiple choice question application and would like to send the value of the answer selected. Here is my js script:

```
lockAnswer = function(value) {
    var x = document.getElementsByName("answer");
    for ( i = 0; i < x.length; i ++ ) x[i].disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("explanation").style.display = "";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: window.location.pathname,  
        data: { "value": document.getElementById('answer').value },
        success: alert(1),
        error: alert(0)
    });
};
```

The answers get locked but no success message or error message is sent out. My node code is:

```
app.post('/test/:username/:testid/:noq/:quesnum', users.answer_selected);

module.exports.answer_selected = function (req,res) {
    console.log("Made it!");
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would recommend to use jQuery's power instead of more verbose for-loop with `document.getElementsByName`, you are anyway using it for AJAX, why not to use for selecting radio inputs?

About radio value. The issue is that according to your code, you have multiple ids on the page, while id must be unique. This is how you can reliably read value of the *checked* input:

```
$('[name=answer]:checked').val()
```

Improved function becomes:

```
lockAnswer = function(value) {
    $('[name=answer]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#explanation').css('disaply', '');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: window.location.pathname,  
        data: { "value":  $('[name=answer]:checked').val() },
        success: function() { alert(1) },
        error: function() { alert(0) }
    });
};
```

There were also another issue. This code `success: alert(1)` will not work as expected, because `success` expects function reference, however `alert(1)` immediately executes and returns `undefined`. You need to wrap it into anonimous function.

Comment: Awsome. Thanks a lot. Got a $ is not defined error afterwards but quickly found out I did not include the jQuery library 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'